# Python code is in one directory, database file is in another. How to open db and process?

Tags: python, database, shelve

I have a directory of db files in folder A. My python code runs from another place.

When I run the following code:

```
path = 'xxx'                    # path to file directory
filenames = os.listdir(path)    # list the directory file names
#pprint.pprint(filenames)       # print names
newest=max(filenames)
print newest                    # print most recent file name

# would like to open this file and write to it
data=shelve.open(newest, flag="w")
```

It works up until the last line, then I get an error which says: `need "n" or "c" flag to run new db`.

Without the flag in the last line eg: `data=shelve.open(newest)`, the file name arrives in the Python code's directory without any data in the db.

I need to be able to put the filename returned by newest in " ", but don't know how.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? Thanks

Comment: That's a peculiar use of `max()`.  Is the DB location fixed (as in, it won't change during the course of running the program)?

Answer (score 4):

`newest` is just the filename (e.g. `test.db`). Since the current directory (by default the directory from which the script was run) is not the same as the db folder, you need to form a full path. You can do that with [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
data = shelve.open(os.path.join(path,newest), flag = "w")
```

As Geoff Gerrietts points out, `max(filenames)` returns the filename that comes last in alphabetical order. Perhaps that does give you the file you desire. But if you want the file with the most recent modification time, then you could use

```
filenames = [os.path.join(path,name) for name in os.listdir(path)]
newest = max(filenames, key = os.path.getmtime)
```

Note that if you do it this way, then `newest` will be a full path name, so you would then not need `os.path.join` in the `shelve.open` line:

```
data = shelve.open(newest, flag = "w")
```

---

By the way, an alternative to using full path names is to change the current directory:

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Although this looks simpler, it can also make your code harder to comprehend, since the reader has to keep track of what the current working directory is.
Perhaps this is not hard if you only call `os.chdir` once, but in a complicated script, calling `os.chdir` in many places can make the code a bit spaghetti-like.

By using full path names there is no question about what you are doing.

---

If you wish to open each file:

```
import os
import contextlib

filenames = [os.path.join(path,name) for name in os.listdir(path)]
for filename in filenames:
    with contextlib.closing(shelve.open(filename, flag = "w")) as data:
        # do stuff with data
        # ...
        # data.close() will be called for you when Python leaves this with-block
```

Comment: unutbu's solution is correct. I am not sure that "max(filenames)" will get you the newest file, as your code suggests. "max(filenames)" will return the alphabetically last filename: max(["c", "b", "e", "a"] => "e".

Comment: Thank you unutbu, works perfectly! Makoto- yes, not a very good use of max() although it does return the newest file. I am n00B and will soon be searching for a better solution!

Comment: Hm. unutbu- this returns File "fileopen.py", line 19, in <module>
    newest=max(filenames, key=os.path.getmtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime ...googling getmtime

Comment: Oops! This is the same issue as before. `os.path.getmtime` needs to be pased a full path, not just the file name. I've edited the post above to show how to fix that.

Comment: So now I have reached the predicted max() problem. What I really want to do is read all of the files filenames = os.listdir(path) and open one by one, grab some data, close the file, move on to the next file.